# Python For loop get index

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I am writing a simple Python for loop to prnt the current character in a string. However, I could not get the index of the character. Here is what I have, does anyone know a good way to get the current index of the character in the loop?

```
 loopme = 'THIS IS A VERY LONG STRING WITH MANY MANY WORDS!'

 for w  in loopme:
    print "CURRENT WORD IS " + w + " AT CHARACTER "
```

Comment: Aside from the numbering issue, are you sure this is what you want? `w` is the current character, not word.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate the index along with the elements of the sequence you are looping over:

```
for index, w in enumerate(loopme):
    print "CURRENT WORD IS", w, "AT CHARACTER", index
```

Comment: so with the enumerate() function, you need to define two variables? one for the index and one for the characters?

Comment: @user1817081: You don't *have* to; you are now looping over something that yields two-value tuples. Using tuple unpacking just makes it easier to 'receive' them.

Comment: @user1817081: You can also do `for elem in enumerate(loopme)`, then use `elem[[0]` for the index value and `elem[1]` for the character, but that is just more cumbersome.

Comment: Gotcha, so enumerate() is creating a map of the string. I am guessing this will also apply to a List?

Comment: @user1817081: `enumerate()` can be used on *any* sequence. It doesn't create a map, it simply keeps a counter. Every time the `for` construct asks for the next element, it in turn asks the wrapped sequence for the next item, then returns the value of the counter together with that next value from the wrapped sequence, then increments the internal counter.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to iterate over characters or words?

For words, you'll have to split the words first, such as

```
for index, word in enumerate(loopme.split(" ")):
    print "CURRENT WORD IS", word, "AT INDEX", index
```

This prints the index of the word.

For the absolute character position you'd need something like

```
chars = 0
for index, word in enumerate(loopme.split(" ")):
    print "CURRENT WORD IS", word, "AT INDEX", index, "AND AT CHARACTER", chars
    chars += len(word) + 1
```